# get the data from html frames

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, html-frames

I try to get the tables information in [this](https://www.og.decc.gov.uk/information/wells/pprs/Well_production_onshore_oil_fields/onshore_oil_fields_by_well/onshore_oil_fields_by_well.htm) html frames.  I mean the tables having columns:

```
Year,Month,Oil Production m3,Gas Production Ksm3,...
```

Using `beautifulSoup`, This is so far what I have tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen, urlretrieve, quote

url_base = 'https://www.og.decc.gov.uk/information/wells/pprs/Well_production_onshore_oil_fields/onshore_oil_fields_by_well/onshore_oil_fields_by_wel.html'
u = urlopen(url_base)
html = u.read().decode('utf-8')
u.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

But this retrieve only the main page info, not the page frames. 
When I change the url base by the frame link , it tells me that the requested page is outdated.

Comment: Please explain more clear what's your problem , because when I load the page I see all pages in the sidebar menu, and just you ahve to click or reference it's url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are copying the wrong url. When I use the following, it worked.

```
url_base = 'https://www.og.decc.gov.uk/information/wells/pprs/Well_production_onshore_oil_fields/onshore_oil_fields_by_well/0.htm'
```

Attention: it is `.../onshore_oil_fields_by_well/0.htm`,

instead of `.../onshore_oil_fields_by_well/0.html`

Comment: My bad ! thanks! I think I have to go to the coffee machine !